# How to stop the previous instances of the same function if it's called multiple times?

Tags: javascript, function, multiple-instances

I have written a custom animation function. It usually works just fine, but when I call `animate();` in rapid succession with different endCallbacks, sometimes the callbacks overlap really badly, causing the wrong action at the wrong time.

The problem is that the function instantiates multiple times and executes untill the endValue is reached. The currentValue is changed so fast that I get to see just the last value in my html page animation. This hiddes this unwanted behavior.

What I need when I call `animate();` a second time is to end the first instance of `animate();` and trigger a new one with new values and a new callback. Also at the same time I want to stop the `setTimeout()` function just to make sure no wrong callback is triggered.

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.addEventListener('click', // some button
        function (){
            animate(1, 10);
        }, false
    );
}

function animate(startValue, endValue, callback, endCallback) {
    var startValue = startValue,
        currentValue = startValue,
        endValue = endValue,
        callback = callback,
        timeout = null;

    loopAnimation();
    function loopAnimation(){
        if (currentValue != endValue){
            timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                currentValue++;

                // Callback executes some page manipulation code
                if (typeof callback !== "undefined") callback(currentValue); 
                console.log(currentValue);
                loopAnimation();
            },500)
        } else {
            console.log("This callback triggers some specific changes in my page");
            if (typeof endCallback !== "undefined") endCallback();
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of seeing in the console: 
1,2,3, - 1,4,2,5 ... 6,9,7,10,8,9,10

I'd like to see just: 
1,2,3, - 1,2 ... 7,8,9,10

However, keep in mind that because of the way I use `animate()` in my script I can't relly on knowing the name or scope of the input variables. This cuts me from being able to solve it myself.

Comment: You can't halt the execution of one function from another. Assuming you are using jquery for animation, there is a `.stop` method you can call on an element to stop any animation running on that element. http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 2):

While it isn't quite the implementation you're asking for, I wonder if Underscore's throttle or debounce would meet the need?

[debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) will make sure your function is called no more than X times per second -- it'll still be executed once per every time called, but the subsequent calls will be delayed to meet your rate limit. So if you called animate twice in quick succession, debounce can delay the second execution until 100ms after the first or what have you.

[throttle](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) will basically ignore calls that occur during the rate limit. So if you call your animate 10 times within 100ms, you could have it throw out all but the first. (Actually, it'll do the first one, plus one at at the end of the wait period).

You don't need to use all of underscore to get these methods; I've seen people frequently copy and pasting just the debounce and/or throttle functions from underscore. If you google, you can find some standalone throttle or debounce implementations.

Throttle and debounce are commonly used in just your case, animation.

For your original spec, to actually "end the first instance of animate()" -- there's no great reliable way to do that in javascript. There's no real general purpose way to 'cancel' a function already being executed. If you can make it work with debounce or throttle, I think it will lead to less frustration.

Comment: I need to be able to change on the fly the state of the animating object, so preventing double clicks it's not really an option for my purpose. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to store the last timeout id you used. So next time you start a new animation, you clear any ongoing animation using this timeout id and `clearTimeout`.
I found convenient to store the interval on the function itself.

See the jsbin here :
 http://jsbin.com/nadawezete/1/edit?js,console,output

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.addEventListener('click', // some button
        function (){
            animate(1, 10);
        }, false
    );
};

function animate(startValue, endValue, callback, endCallback) {   
    var currentValue = startValue;
    if (animate.timeout) clearTimeout(animate.timeout);
    loopAnimation();
    function loopAnimation(){
        if (currentValue != endValue){
            animate.timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                console.log(currentValue);
                currentValue++;    
                // Callback executes some page manipulation code
                if (callback ) callback(currentValue); 
                loopAnimation();
            },500);
        } else {
            console.log("This callback triggers some specific changes in my page");
            if (endCallback) endCallback();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very close to what I was looking for. For my specific use case, it works very well, and I can adapt this solution a bit further by making an object that holds multiple setTimeout(); ids for multiple animated variables. This will help at animating diferent objects without reseting the animation for the wrong object. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome ! So it seems like you could accept this as a answer. Mind that if you perform 'a lot' (20+??) of animation, setTimeout overhead might get too big an cause you issues. You'll have to revert the logic and have a single handler hooked on setInterval or requestAnimationFrame that drives all the animation logic.

Comment: In my current project I do use requestAnimationFrame(); for multiple canvas and page manipulations and, indeed, it really improves the overall performance by a noticeable measure. I simplified the exemple code in order to make the unwanted behavior easy to notice. I will replace clearTimeout(); with cancelAnimationFrame(); Your feedback is much appreciated!